# How can I make permission for a special Id

Tags: python-3.x, discord, permissions, discord.py, python-3.10

I am building a public discord.py bot and I want that I can use every feature even if I don't have the rights on that server like:

I am on a server and they're using my bot but I have no rights but I still could use clear or anything
I am sorry if this question could be easily answered on the docs but the best I found was this:

```
@commands.bot_has_role(11132312313213)
```

my code looks like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=11):
    if (not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages):
        await ctx.send('Du hast keine ``Rechte`` für diesen Command! Wende dich bitte an einen Supporter :)')
        return
    amount = amount+1
    if amount > 101:
        await ctx.send('Sorry Bre nur 100 Nachrichten werden hier gelöscht')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await ctx.send('Cleared!', delete_after=3)
```

too lazy to read:
Permissions for User ID

I tried to look into the Docs, searched it on google and youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a if query, where the permissions and the useris is checked.

your code would like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=11):
    userid = YOUR_USERID_AS_INTEGER
    if not (ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages or ctx.author.id == userid):
        await ctx.send('Du hast keine ``Rechte`` für diesen Command! Wende dich bitte an einen Supporter :)')
        return
    amount = amount+1
    if amount > 101:
        await ctx.send('Sorry Bre nur 100 Nachrichten werden hier gelöscht')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await ctx.send('Cleared!', delete_after=3)
```

the variable `userid` would be your userid as integer (e.g.: 204050461957941234)